# verticall image scrolling

Tags: php, sql, image, scroll

I am new to PHP and working for one small project. I want vertical image scroller. All images are fetching from database (sql). the problem is after the last image there is blank white space. this white space is visible till the last image reached to the TOP. I want continuous scrolling. after last image, first image should be in queue . Please help

Comment: You should post relevant code. Question is unclear...But probably you can solve your problem using some jQuery slider...

Answer (score 0):

Such UI effect should be taken care of on client-side using some jQuery plug-in such as [Vertical Scrolling Image Gallery with jQuery and jQuery UI - Scroll Slider](http://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/Vertical-Scrolling-Image-Gallery-with-jQuery-jQuery-UI-Scroll-Slider.html)